# Python message cache for comet?

Tags: python, comet, tornado, mq

I can best describe what I'm looking for with an example of a simplified version. One of the demos for Tornado is a simple chat server:

https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/chat/chatdemo.py

I'm interested in the `MessageMixin` class here. It keeps a static-length backlog of messages, and when new messages are available, it returns the slice of the message list that's new. Or that's what it appears to do. I know that I've implemented something like that before when writing a simple comet app.

So has anyone generalized this and added fancy things to it? I'm particularly interested in  a way to manage many channels of communication and delete ones that haven't been used in a while. Persistence might also be useful.

Is this something an MQ can do?

Comment: Could you add some more information about your intended use-case? As it stands your solution could lie any between time based lookups from a database to XMPP to some kind of pub/sub implementation.

Comment: Chat with multiple channels created by users on demand, where unused channels die out after a period without new messages. Time-based lookups in a database sounds good, but how would a client be notified if it's waiting for new messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Redis](http://redis.io/) has a [publish/subscribe](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) feature, along with additional [data structure-oriented commands](http://redis.io/commands/) which you can use to persist and expire the message backlog, list users in a given room, or other attributes associated with them.  The protocol is text-based and is a superset of the Memcached commands.

Here is a description which uses [chat as an example of pub/sub](http://rediscookbook.org/pubsub_for_synchronous_communication.html) along with a [Ruby example using Websocket](https://gist.github.com/348262), and a snippet in Python which uses [Websocket, Tornado and Redis pub/sub](http://thomas.pelletier.im/2010/08/websocket-tornado-redis/) to implement a simple chat room.

Based on the information in your question, a dedicated message queue (like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)) may also be useful to you. It is hard to say without knowing what you need in the areas of message volume, fault-tolerance, replication, etc. Redis may also be what you're looking for, but if nothing else it is pretty simple and could help you get a prototype running quickly to further nail down your app's requirements.

Comment: Thank you. Redis looks perfect. Didn't know it did pub/sub.